# Version of Linux Mint apt itself

Tags: linux-mint, apt

How do you check the version of apt package manager on Linux Mint? I'm not talking about the packages, but the apt itself. For instance, for dpkg,

```
dpkg --version
```

returns its correct version. Is there an equivalent for apt?

Comment: did you tried `apt --version`?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yup, doesn't work. Simply lists out commands

Comment: Strange. So you should add the version of your Debian distribution. On my Debian [buster, aka 10, aka stable] the above command give me the version of `apt`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Ah, I'm sorry. I thought Linux Mint was Debian. I'm using Linux Mint  19.1, and the above command does not work sadly.

Comment: Linux Mint comes in multiple flavours (see [here](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php)). Some are based on Debian, some on Ubuntu (which itself is based on Debian). Maybe `apt --version` is a recent `apt` feature, but if `apt-get --version` also does not work, it really is strange.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch apt-get --version indeed did return the same version as the method you mentioned below!

Comment: @EricPark After some googling I found several sources stating that Linux Mint has an additional wrapper around Debians `apt` (`/usr/bin/apt`), which has a different feature set and is located at `/usr/local/bin/apt`. This explains why your `apt` is different than "our" `apt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for some reason `apt --version` does not seem to work for you, you can check via `apt list`, which version of apt is installed:

`apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep ^apt/`

On my Ubuntu 20.10, the result is `apt/groovy,now 2.1.10 amd64 [installed,automatic]`, so the version is `2.1.10` (which is also what `apt --version` is telling me).

Explanation:

1. `apt list --installed` shows all installed packages.
2. `2>/dev/null` silences the warning that `apt` always shows when it is used in pipes (just for convenience, not necessary)
3. `grep ^apt/` filters out all lines which do not start with `apt/`, so you don't have to scroll through all installed packages

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian 10.5 "apt --version" or "apt -v" shows the version of the apt command.

Comment: On my Linux Mint 19.1, "apt --version" or "apt -v" results the same as "apt --help" :(

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.10 both commands print `apt 2.1.10 (amd64)`. Strange, indeed.